# Why \b is not returning expected output in the below regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to search for && in the below text:

```
'if a + b > 0 && a - b < 0:'
```

I am able to extract && by the below regex :

```
  r'(?<=\s)&&(?=\s+)'
```

As per my understanding, I should be able to extract && by surrounding the re by\b (work boundary)

```
r'\b&&\b'
```

Why this doesn't work?

Comment: `&` is not a word character hence `\b` on either side won't work.

Comment: `\b` matches the following scenarios: `^\w` or `\w$` or `\W\w` or `\W\w`. Since a combination of `&` and space never satisfies any of these (neither character is contained in `\w`), you'll never match `&&` with `\b`

Comment: Understood. Thank you !!

Comment: You are probably looking for `\B&&\B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\B&&\B`. `\b` is for word boundary and `\B` is for not a word boundary.

And as mentioned by [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava), `&&` is not a word but 2 individual characters. so `\B&&\B` should work fine.

Comment: This will also match some things that the OP probably does not want, like &&&& or "&&" (including quotes). This may or may not matter, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: I agree with &&&& case but not with "&&". Well thats what i tried with https://regexr.com

Comment: Why would you explicitly require a word boundary to not be present? This fails to match `a&&b` whero presumably the OP would like for that to match, too. Just don't put anything around `&&` or maybe put in lookarounds... or use a proper parser if you are actually trying to parse expressions.